# Dependency injection on Laravel 5.5 not working after delete unused class

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control, autowired

This was working flawless, but I removed some unused class and now the autowiring feature of laravel is not resolving the type-hinted dependencies.

I have declared in `AppServiceProvider.php` various bindings for service classes, which dependencies should be resolved by autowiring, but there aren't.

I leave an example code of `AppServiceProvider.php` and a class `ProductoService.php`

What I am missing here? Thanks in advance!

#### Error

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   App\Services\ProductoService::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   /home/eznb/Documentos/osiris/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php on
>   line 44 and exactly 1 expected

#### AppServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\CajaService;
use App\Services\PrecioService;
use App\Services\ProductoService;
use App\Services\ServicioService;
use App\Services\TrabajoService;
use App\Services\TurnoService;
use Calendar;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {

            $event_list = [];

            $calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list);
            $view->with('calendar_details', $calendar_details);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(PrecioService::class, function ($app) {
            return new PrecioService();
        });
        $this->app->bind(ProductoService::class, function ($app) {
            return new ProductoService();
        });
        $this->app->bind(ServicioService::class, function ($app) {
            return new ServicioService();
        });
        $this->app->bind(CajaService::class, function ($app) {
            return new CajaService();
        });
        $this->app->bind(TrabajoService::class, function ($app) {
            return new TrabajoService();
        });
        $this->app->bind(TurnoService::class, function ($app) {
            return new TurnoService();
        });
    }
}
```

#### ProductoService.php

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Producto;
use App\Services\PrecioService;

class ProductoService
{
    protected $precio_service;

    public function __construct(PrecioService $precio_service)
    {
        $this->precio_service = $precio_service;
    }
.
.
.
some more core
.
.
.
```

Comment: Your trying to instantiatie `ProductoService` without a parameter, which it obviously needs

Comment: that should be resolved by the service container. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#automatic-injection

Comment: Not when you're binding a class in the Service container though.

Comment: ok I will test it, but how this was working like so until yesterday? there is some kind of cache class resolution that maybe was resolving somehow the type-hinted classes?

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer that question.

Comment: Thanks @Daan for your answer

Comment: Remove all those bindings, not a single class has anything special to resolve, they will be resolved without needing bindings

Comment: you were right @lagbox. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please Change your AppServiceProvider.php to Below

```
 namespace App\Providers;
use App\Services\CajaService;
use App\Services\PrecioService;
use App\Services\ProductoService;
use App\Services\ServicioService;
use App\Services\TrabajoService;
use App\Services\TurnoService;
use Calendar;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {

            $event_list = [];

            $calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list);
            $view->with('calendar_details', $calendar_details);
        });
    }


    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(PrecioService::class, function ($app) {
            return new PrecioService();
        });
        $this->app->bind(ProductoService::class, function ($app) {
            return new ProductoService($app[PrecioService::class]); // Here i made the change as you ProductoService constructort has as its dependency
        });
        $this->app->bind(ServicioService::class, function ($app) {
            return new ServicioService();
        });
        $this->app->bind(CajaService::class, function ($app) {
            return new CajaService();
        });
        $this->app->bind(TrabajoService::class, function ($app) {
            return new TrabajoService();
        });
        $this->app->bind(TurnoService::class, function ($app) {
            return new TurnoService();
        });
    }
```

i have used $app[PrecioService::class] to resolve from the service container as you have register it in this line $this->app->bind(PrecioService::class, function ($app) {
                return new PrecioService();
            });
May this will solve your query. If you are unclear you can comment below. I will explain in detail if required.